# Tiled Terrain Normals

Tags: three.js

I am trying to create a terrain solution in ThreeJS and I'm running into some trouble with the generation of the normals. I am approaching the problem by creating a number of mesh objects using the THREE.PlaneGeometry class. Once all of the tiles have been created I go through each and set the UV's so that each tile represents a part of the whole. I also generate a height value of the vertex Y positions to create some hills. I then call the geometry functions

```
geometry.computeFaceNormals(); 
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

This is just so that I have some default face and vertex normals for each tile.

I then go through each tile and try to average out the normals on each corner.

The problem is (I think) with the normals, but I don't really know what to call this problem. Each of the normals on the plane's corners point in the same direction as the face when created. This makes the terrain look like a flat shaded object. To prevent this I thought perhaps what I needed to do was make sure each vertext normal (each corner) had the same averaged normal as its immediate neighbours normals. I.E each corner of each tile has the same normal as all the immediate normals around it from the adjacent planes.

figure A
[image]

Here I am visualising each of the 4 normals on the mesh. You can see that at each corner the normals are the same (On top of eachother)

figure B
[image]

EDIT
figure C
[image]

EDIT
Figure D
[image]

Except even when the verts all share the same normals it still comes up all blocky <:/

I don't know how to do this... I think my understanding of what needs to be done is incorrect...?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically right about what should happen. The shading you're getting is not consistent with continuous normals. If each all the vertex-faces at a given location have the same normal you should not see the clear shading discontinuities in your second image.   However the image doesn't look like simple face normals either, at least not to my eye.

A couple of things to look at:

1) I note that your quads themselves are not planar. Is it possible your algorithm is assuming that they are? the non-planar quad meshes don't have real 'face normal' to use as a base.

2) Are your normalized normalized after you average them? That is, do they have a vector length of 1?

3) Are you confident that the normal averaging code is actually using the correct normals to average?  The shading in this does not look like completely flat shaded image where each vertex-face normal in a quad is the same - if that were the case you'd get consistent shading across each quad although the quads would not be continuous.  This it possible your original vertex-face normals are not in fact lined up with the face normals?

4) Try turning off the bump maps to debug. Depending on how the bump is being done in your shader you may have incorrect binormals/bitangents rather than bad vert normals.

Comment: Hi theodox, thanks for helping me with this.
1) Basically the mesh is created using the THREE.PlaneGeomerty class. From what I can see it uses Face4, 4 verts, and 4 indices. When I manipulate the height, I first set the 0th vertex to be the height (vertices[0]) and each of the other verts look at their neighbour mesh's first vertex to get their postions. I'm not sure if this is being used incorrectly... but when I make the terrain as a single plane object whose vertices are moved in the same way it seems to work as expected.

Comment: 2 - 3) Yes each of the normals are normalized. If I dont use the averaging algorithm I get what you can see in figure C (question edited above). After my algorithm is applied you can see the normals are all on top of each other and therefore must be the same and correct. Figure D is the face centroids and their normals.

4) Turning of bump and specular did not solve the problem either.

I have a question though - do the face normals have to be averaged out aswell? (So not just the vertex normals)

Comment: If the mesh were a triangle mesh, you would first set all the vertex-face normals to match their triangle's face normal, than for each set of coincident normals you average and renormalize.  For quads it's a bit tougher, because a nonplanar quad has no 'normal' you  can rely on - if it's a bowtie (opposite sides have opposite slopes) it's going to shade wierdly, and  I think that's what you're seeing.  If the mesh is deformed only in Z, you could calculate the normals with a spline running along each edge line - that's the usual heightmap method.  Or, you could convert the quad mesh to tris.

Comment: Looking more carefully at the debug image, you can see the 'bent face normals' in image C.  Look at the top right corner. Each quad's normals should be red, green, yellow, blue in clockwise order, and if the quad were planar they'd be parallel. the quad on the top edge, one in from the right is like this -- but the quad just below it is not.

Comment: This tutorial http://grahamweldon.com/posts/view/3d-terrain-generation-with-three-js referenced in one of the other 3js posts might help you walk through it

Comment: Thanks again theodox. I'll have to try and do it in Tri's instead of quads I guess. The tutorial Graham does just uses a single plane mesh unfortunately whereas I am using multiple meshes placed next to each other. Which is why I don't understand why it doesnt work with quads. When you use a single mesh, it uses quads (and shares corner normals) and comes out fine. But when you use multiple meshes next to each other (also quads and sharing the same normal) it doesn't <:S I'll have to try Tri's and see if this works

Comment: After triangulating the mesh and averaging out the normals - the tool now works as expected, Thanks @theodox :D

Comment: For lurkers: that sounds like the API is doing the right thing inside the vertex array of the plane object, but it's not the same as what you were trying to do between plane objects.  Glad it's solved

Answer (score 1):

Instead of averaging at each vertex / corner the neighborhood normals you should average the four normals that each vertex has (4 tiles meet at each vertex).

Comment: Hi Gaitat, so do you mean that each 'corner normal' is calculated as its 4 (self inclusive) neighboring face normals then divided by 4?

Comment: Hi Gaitat, I tried that and unfortunately it still creates the same effect <:/